# Extra view appears on screen after adding UITabBar in iOS13

Tags: swift, ios13, xcode11

I'm adding a `UITabBar` to my view and I get a weird `UITabBarController` like view on the screen! The Xcode is the latest version, 11.0:
[image]

This is the storyboard:
[image]

The tab bar is constrained to the trailing, leading and bottom of the safe area. I even applied UITabBarController workaround fix to it which seems not to work.

*This so-called fix only hides the first `UITabBar` item from the tab bar.*

```
 class UITabBariOS13: UITabBar {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        if subviews.count > 0 {
            subviews[0].isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied an existing tab bar from another project (pre-iOS13) and pasted in the view and worked fine!